# How do I create a character string in R which keeps apostrophes?

Tags: sql, r, apostrophe

I am trying to create a character string in R, which I can then use to call a SQL stored procedure.

```
Websites  <- paste('UK,','DE,','CA,', 'US', sep = " ")
print(Websites)

[1] "UK, DE, CA, US"
```

How do I change this for the output:

```
"'UK', 'DE', 'CA', 'US"?
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `gsub`

```
gsub("\\b(\\w+)\\b", "'\\1'", Websites)
#[1] "'UK', 'DE', 'CA', 'US'"
```

---

Or another option is

```
paste(sQuote(c('UK','DE','CA', 'US')), collapse=" ")
```

Comment: Wasn't familiar with sQuote. I had `paste0("'", c('UK,','DE,','CA,', 'US,'), "'", collapse = " ")` which I guess is equivalent

Comment: Just one detail on `sQuote`, it will use fancy quotes rather than escaped `'` and  `"` unless you set the proper options `options(useFancyQuotes = FALSE)`. That's caused me some grief in the past.

Answer (score 0):

you could simply do

```
library(magrittr)
Websites<-"UK, DE, CA, US" %>% gsub("(\\w+)", "'\\1'", .)
print(Websites)
#[1] "'UK', 'DE', 'CA', 'US'"
```

Comment: Why complicate this simple answer by using `magrittr` and a pipe?

Comment: it exposes the input, improving readability, which makes it easier to modify. For me, readability is the best thing about magrittr, despite all the headaches it gives in some codes and the naming of operations (blergh!)

Comment: Readability is the *only* thing about `magrittr` - and in the case of multiply nested function calls I think pipes are a huge improvement. However, for a single function call I find a pipe much less readable. And for a basic SO Q&A, that doesn't need any packages that load `%>%`, a single pipe will likely confuse new users who haven't seen it before. I haven't downvoted, but I do think it makes your answer less accessible and therefore lower quality.